# yAxis title is not visible. (highcharts)

Tags: charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am developing spline chart.

And this is my yAxis:

```
[
  {
    "title": {
      "text": "Head (ft)",
      "margin": 0,
      "x": -5
    },
    "labels": {
      "format": "{value:.0f}",
      "x": -5
    },
    "visible": true,
    "opposite": true
  }
]
```

But yAxis title is not visible.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Works with a basic [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/f5nunbyq/), therefore, more information is needed.

Comment: Please provide a live demo showing the problem. **ewolden** showed you a working demo and I am also unable to recreate the issue. You could edit the demo from above comment.